# how to open link in external window with click on anchor tag with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

This is probably such a noob question, but I can't get it to work.

I want to open external window link by clicking on anchor tag, but I keep getting error that `myFunction()` is not defined.

```
<a href="#" id="searchEng" onclick="myFunction()">Open link</a>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#searchEng').click(function() {
        const engine = document.getElementById('engine');
        var en_ = engine.val();
        if (en_ == "firefox")
        {
            function myFunction() {
                var url = "https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/";
                window.open(url,'_blank');
            };
        }
    });
));
```

Why is it undefined?

I have `.js` included because other stuff works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove function inside click function

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#searchEng').click(function() {
        const engine = document.getElementById('engine');
        var en_ = engine.val();
        if (en_ == "firefox")
        {
            var url = "https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/";
            window.open(url,'_blank');
        }
    });

<a href="#" id="searchEng">Open link</a>
```

Comment: oh yes, i see it now. such a stupid mistake. thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You declared `myFunction` inside another function, which makes it a local variable of that function. Local variables aren't available outside the function where they were defined.